# Can a "super" SVG path be defined by children <path>?

Tags: svg, path, grouping, fill

I had in mind that SVG would somehow allow to define a shape thanks to several paths defining its borders - implicitly or explicitly closed, or open.

I tried this :

```
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200"
   height="200"
   viewBox="0 0 120 120"
   version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <path d="M 20,20 40,20 40,60 100,60 100,100" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:3px;" id="Border1" />
    <path d="M 100,100 L 20,100 20,20" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:2px;" id="Border2" />
  </defs>
  <g style="fill: green">
    <use xlink:href = "#Border1"/>
    <use xlink:href = "#Border2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Filling in the group with some colour clearly shows that each path is considered individually, not as a whole.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this ?

1. To be able to manipulate each border individualy
2. To be define some shapes by their borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is not.

Something like this has been proposed and discussed in the SVG Working Group. But that's as far as it has got so far.

You could write some Javascript to build the regions from a set of border paths.

```js
var regions = document.querySelectorAll("path.region");
regions.forEach(function(region) {
  // Get the value of the "data-paths" attribute
  var borderIds = region.dataset.borders.split(',');
  var regionPath = "";
  // Find all the border paths for this region, and add them to the region's path data
  borderIds.forEach(function(id) {
    var borderDef = document.getElementById(id);
    var d = borderDef.getAttribute("d");
    if (regionPath === "") {
       // First border in region
       regionPath = d;
    } else {
       // Subsequent borders need their first 'M' changed to an 'L' to keep the path contiguous
       regionPath += 'L' + d.substr(1);
    }
  })
  region.setAttribute("d", regionPath);
});
```

```html
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200"
   height="200"
   viewBox="0 0 120 120"
   version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <path d="M 20,20 40,20 40,60 100,60 100,100" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:3px;" id="Border1" />
    <path d="M 100,100 L 20,100 20,20" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:2px;" id="Border2" />
  </defs>
  <path style="fill: green" class="region" data-borders="Border1,Border2"/>
</svg>
```

Not that code only works if the next border path, in the list of borders, starts where the last one finished.

Also, this code assumes the browser supports the `dataset` attribute on SVG elements.  If you need to support older browsers, you may need to use `getAttribute("data-borders")` instead.